# wxPython multiple windows scope issue

Tags: python, scope, wxpython

I'm trying to hone my Python skills by creating a simple app to organize an itinerary. The basis of the app is that you enter the task to add, then another window pops out to ask for the due date and priority of the task. The second window has a submit button that is supposed to add all the gathered information to a list box with multiple columns.

My issue is where to create an array to hold the information so that it can be added. I can't add it to the add function itself, because it needs to be referenced by other functions.

I've tried adding it to the `__init__` of my MainWindow, but that's where I get stuck. I don't know how to reference the array once it's there. Simply referencing the name (toAdd) give me exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Making GUI - First Shot (Development).py", line 60, in AddItem
    toAdd.append(appendItem)
NameError: global name 'toAdd' is not defined
```

Here's my code:

```
import wx

class mainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(650, 500))

        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        hbox1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        hbox2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        menubar = wx.MenuBar()

        topFont = wx.Font(20, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL)

        self.topLabel = wx.StaticText(panel, size = (-1, -1), label="Itinerary")

        font = wx.Font(10, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL)

        self.topLabel.SetFont(topFont)

        vbox.Add(self.topLabel, 0, wx.ALL, 2)

        vbox.Add((-1, 10))

        self.listBox = wx.ListCtrl(panel, style = wx.LC_REPORT)
        self.listBox.InsertColumn(0, "Priority", width = 150)
        self.listBox.InsertColumn(0, "Due Date (if applicable)", width = 250)
        self.listBox.InsertColumn(0, "Task", width=250)

        self.listBox.SetFont(font)
        vbox.Add(self.listBox, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 2)

        hbox1.Add((5, -1))

        self.newItemInput = wx.TextCtrl(panel, size = (400, -1))
        hbox2.Add(self.newItemInput, 1, wx.ALIGN_LEFT | wx.ALL, 1)

        self.submitButton = wx.Button(panel, size = (100, -1))
        self.submitButton.SetLabel("Hello")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.AddItem, self.submitButton)
        hbox2.Add(self.submitButton,  1, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT | wx.ALL, 2)

        vbox.Add(hbox1, 0, wx.ALL, 2)
        vbox.Add(hbox2, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 2)

        vbox.Add((-1, 35))

        panel.SetSizer(vbox)

        self.Show(True)

        toAdd = []

    def AddItem(self, event):
        appendItem = self.newItemInput.GetValue()
        toAdd.append(appendItem)
        confirmBox = wx.Frame(frame, title = "Task Details", size = (300, 150))
        confirmVert = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        confirmHoriz1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        confirmHoriz2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        confirmHoriz3 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        confirmHoriz4 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        confirmPrompt = wx.StaticText(confirmBox, size = (25, -1), label = "Due Date for " + toAdd[0])
        confirmHoriz1.Add(confirmPrompt, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALIGN_CENTER)

        addingDate = wx.TextCtrl(confirmBox, size = (25, -1))
        confirmHoriz2.Add(addingDate, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALIGN_CENTER)

        confirmPriority = wx.StaticText(confirmBox, size = (25, -1), label = "Priority")
        confirmHoriz3.Add(confirmPriority, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALIGN_CENTER)

        addingPriority = wx.TextCtrl(confirmBox, size = (25, -1))
        confirmHoriz4.Add(addingPriority, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALIGN_CENTER)

        addListButton = wx.Button(confirmBox, size = (-1, 25), label = "Submit")

        confirmVert.Add(confirmHoriz1, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        confirmVert.Add(confirmHoriz2, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        confirmVert.Add(confirmHoriz3, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        confirmVert.Add(confirmHoriz4, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        confirmVert.Add(addListButton, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALIGN_CENTER)

        def itemSubmit(self):
            date = addingDate.GetValue()
            priority = addingPriority.GetValue()
            toAdd.append(date)
            toAdd.append(priority)
            panel.listBox.Append(toAdd)

        confirmBox.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, itemSubmit, addListButton)



        confirmBox.SetSizer(confirmVert)
        confirmBox.Show()

app = wx.App(False)
frame = mainWindow(None, "Itinerary Manager")

app.MainLoop()
```

How would I go about making AddItem append the information to toAdd so that I can then append toAdd to the ListCtrl on the main window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilise the `self` reference for your data items, so declare

```
toAdd = []
```

as

```
self.toAdd[]
```

this should apply to your other variables as well.
The first argument of every class method, including **init**, is always a reference to the current instance of the class. By convention, this argument is always named self. It isn't a rule just a convention.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. This seems to have solved my problem.

Comment: So, after I made the suggested change, I end up with this error:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Making GUI - First Shot (Development).py", line 91, in itemSubmit
    self.toAdd.append(date)
AttributeError: 'CommandEvent' object has no attribute 'toAdd'`

Comment: I expected you would be back. Your `def itemSubmit(self):` is a `def` within a `def`, rather than a separate `def` with the class and you aren't declaring the event. It should be `def itemSubmit(self,event):`. However this is essentially a completely different question and your code as it stands has more than one speed bump, which you will hit along the way but that is the frustration and the beauty of learning a new coding language.

Comment: You're certainly not wrong. I appreciate you pointing me in the right direction. I'll see what I can find.